# Can't retrieve ID from an insert in JDBC with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to get the **ID** of an insert row which is `auto_increment` in MySQL. I'm using the parameter `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` in the `prepareStatement` method and trying to obtain it via the `getGeneratedKeys` method. Somehow, it is not retrieving the **ID**.

It should be noted that the insertion is done, but since the **ID** is not obtained, I cannot perform the other inserts and that is why it gives me the error `"MySQL ERROR 1452"`, because an insert is being made later with the **ID 0** that does not exist.

```java
public int insertar(Compra objC, ArrayList<DetalleCompra> listaDetalle) {
    try {
        conexion = MySQLConexion.conexion();
        
        conexion.setAutoCommit(false);
        
        procedimientoAlmacenado = conexion.prepareStatement("{call insertar_compra (?, ?)}", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        
        fecha = FORMATO_FECHA.parse(objC.getFecha());
        fechaSQL = new java.sql.Date(fecha.getTime());
        
        procedimientoAlmacenado.setDate(1, fechaSQL);
        procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(2, objC.getIdCliente());
        
        resultado = procedimientoAlmacenado.executeUpdate();
        
        int idCompra = 0;
        
        ResultSet idGenerada = procedimientoAlmacenado.getGeneratedKeys();
            
        if (idGenerada.next()) {
            idCompra = idGenerada.getInt(1);
        }
        
        if (resultado != 0) {
            for (DetalleCompra x : listaDetalle) {
                procedimientoAlmacenado = conexion.prepareCall("{call insertar_detalle_compra (?, ?, ?)}");
                
                procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(1, idCompra);
                procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(2, x.getIdProducto());
                procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(3, x.getCantidad());
                
                resultado = procedimientoAlmacenado.executeUpdate();
                
                procedimientoAlmacenado = conexion.prepareCall("{disminuir_stock (?, ?)}");
                
                procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(1, x.getIdProducto());
                procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(2, x.getCantidad());
                
                resultado = procedimientoAlmacenado.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
        
        conexion.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        
        try {
            conexion.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            if (procedimientoAlmacenado != null)
                procedimientoAlmacenado.close();
            
            if (conexion != null)
                conexion.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    return resultado;
}
```

I also tried to create a variable:

```
String[] generatedId = { "ID" };
```

and place it in the method `prepareStatement`:

```
procedimientoAlmacenado = conexion.prepareStatement("{call insertar_compra (?, ?)}", generatedId);
```

However, it doesn't work either. I'm suspecting that it has to do with the fact that I'm doing the statement inside a stored procedure, or with `setAutoCommit(false)`, but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Obtaining the generated keys - generally - only works for DML statements like INSERT (and sometimes others like MERGE, UPDATE and DELETE). It doesn't work for stored procedures. If you want to obtain a value from a stored procedure, you should return it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so what I did was make the stored procedure return me the last inserted ID:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure insertar_compra (in fec datetime, in client_id int, out id int)
begin
    insert into compra values (null, fec, client_id, 'P');
    
    set id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
end; $$
delimiter ;
```

And then I got it with the `registerOutParameter()` method:

```
public int insertar(Compra objC, ArrayList<DetalleCompra> listaDetalle) {
        try {
            conexion = MySQLConexion.conexion();
            
            conexion.setAutoCommit(false);
            
            procedimientoAlmacenado = conexion.prepareCall("{call insertar_compra (?, ?, ?)}");
            
            fecha = FORMATO_FECHA.parse(objC.getFecha());
            
            fechaSQL = new Timestamp(fecha.getTime());
            
            procedimientoAlmacenado.setTimestamp(1, fechaSQL);
            procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(2, objC.getIdCliente());
            procedimientoAlmacenado.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
            
            resultado = procedimientoAlmacenado.executeUpdate();
            
            int idCompra = 0;
            
            idCompra = procedimientoAlmacenado.getInt(3);
            
            if (resultado != 0) {
                for (DetalleCompra x : listaDetalle) {
                    procedimientoAlmacenado = conexion.prepareCall("{call insertar_detalle_compra (?, ?, ?)}");
                    
                    procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(1, idCompra);
                    procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(2, x.getIdProducto());
                    procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(3, x.getCantidad());
                    
                    resultado = procedimientoAlmacenado.executeUpdate();
                    
                    procedimientoAlmacenado = conexion.prepareCall("{call disminuir_stock (?, ?)}");

                    procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(1, x.getIdProducto());
                    procedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(2, x.getCantidad());
                    
                    resultado = procedimientoAlmacenado.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
            
            conexion.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            
            try {
                conexion.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (procedimientoAlmacenado != null)
                    procedimientoAlmacenado.close();
                
                if (conexion != null)
                    conexion.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        
        return resultado;
    }
```

Thanks to [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) for the suggestion!